# The Validity of my question

Tags: discussion, support, scope, asking-questions

I had posted a question 4 days ago regarding Black Magic

My Question:- [How should one know if he is under Black Magic\evil spirits?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53397/how-should-one-know-if-he-is-under-black-magic-evil-spirits)

I have asked the symptoms one will have when he is under Black magic as per **Scriptures**

Isn't this question valid? I have got downvotes and someone had voted to close my question as it is opinion based?

I only wanted to know regarding the validity of the Question and the reason behind the downvotes, So that I can add necessary details in my question :-)

Comment: It's a problem because different users have different opinions .. it happens in many cases when some users feel that a question is off-topic where as some others feel it is on topic .. in this case it is clearly on topic but the user who close voted (and downvoted) does not feel the same.

Comment: It is a valid question. The -ve votes might be I guess because of the way the question is framed, although it's understandable what you are trying to ask, but it is from a western perspective because there is 'no' evil spirit as such in Vedic-derived traditions especially, and no spirit as well, because spirit/soul are western concepts. The terminology used might be turning off some people. So, I would recommend you to rephrase the question in more of a way that makes it within the context of Hindu traditions.